# Почему зацикливается запрос без prior dbms_random.value в запросах с connect by?

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть запрос с `connect by`. 
Во время написания столкнулся с ошибкой:

> ORA-01436: CONNECT BY loop in user data

По советом из интернета я добавил в него строчку `prior dbms_random.value is not  null`.

```
select n, 
       n + level n_sum,
       nvl(prior n, 0) + level - 1 as prior_sum
from         
(
       select 1 as n from   dual
)
connect by 1=1 
and     level < 10
and     nvl(prior n, 0) + level - 1 in  (1, 2, 3, 7)
and     prior dbms_random.value is not  null;
```

Не люблю магию в коде, которую я не понимаю :)

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему без этой строки мой запрос зацикливается, и как добавление рандома исправляет ситуацию?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запрос не зацикливается. Это Oracle думает, что он зациклился. Определение зацикливания в Oracle реализовано очень просто: если у очередной строки, значения всех полей, которые употребляются с `prior`, равно значению этих полей из предыдущего уровня рекурсии, значит запрос зациклился. На каждом уровне хотя бы одно поле, употребленное с prior, должно отличаться. Это и обеспечивает `DBMS_RANDOM`, дающий подряд не повторяющиеся значения.